# How can I make my WordPress site redirect to subdomain once successfully login they will redirect back to root domain

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I make my WordPress site redirect to subdomain once successfully login they will redirect back to root domain.

This is my subdomain -> http://login.anytimegear.co/
This is my rootdomain -> http://www.anytimegear.co/product

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce/Wordpress - Redirect User Login to Homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958422/woocommerce-wordpress-redirect-user-login-to-homepage)

Answer (score 0):

Try login redirect to add this on function.php file

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return 'http://www.anytimegear.co/product';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```